# ReactJS - Uncaught ReferenceError: errors is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui

Disclaimer: I am new to ReactJS and am likely overlooking something very basic :)

That said, I am trying to put together a simple To-Do list with ReactJS and Material-UI and am running into problems debugging errors in the application. It seems that an error handler is not being passed a reference to the error that occurred and I am unsure how or where to start looking. Here is a screen grab of the trace:

[image: Trace]

My index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ToDoList from './ToDoList';

import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';

import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <ToDoList />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

The runtime error is occurring somewhere within the `ToDoList` class itself I believe, but the problem isn't that I have an error so much as it is that I can't seem to debug the error without access to what the errors were.

Help is appreciated!

EDIT: ToDoList code:

```
import React from 'react';

import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

import AddCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircle';
import CheckBoxComplete from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBox';
import CheckBoxIncomplete from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';

const style = {
  button: {
    margin: 12,
  },
  textField: {
    margin: 12,
  },
}

class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      itemFormText: '',
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      fetch('http://192.168.86.31:5000/api/todoitems')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          this.setState({
            items: result
          });
        });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AddItemForm
          value={this.state.itemFormText}
          onChange={(e) => {
            this.setState({
              items: this.state.items.slice(),
              itemFormText: e.target.value
            });
          }}
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            fetch('http://192.168.86.31:5000/api/todoitems', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ name: this.state.itemFormText }),
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
              })
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then((result) => {
                const items = this.state.items.concat(result);
                console.log(items);
                /*
                this.setState({
                  items: items,
                  itemFormText: ''
                });
                */
              });
          }}
        />
        <Items items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Items extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const items = this.props.items;

    if (items.length === 0) {
      return <div>Nothing to do!</div>;
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <List>
        {
          items.map(i => (
            <ListItem
              key={i.id}
              primaryText={i.name}
              leftIcon={ i.isComplete ? <CheckBoxComplete /> : <CheckBoxIncomplete /> }
              />
          ))
        }
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AddItemForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const buttonEnabled = (this.props.value.length > 0);
    return (
      <form>
        <TextField
          hintText="Don't Forget To..."
          style={style.textField}
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          value={this.props.value} />
        <Button
          label="Add Item"
          primary={buttonEnabled}
          disabled={!buttonEnabled}
          icon={<AddCircle />}
          style={style.button}
          onClick={this.props.onSubmit} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default ToDoList;
```

UPDATE:
This appears to be some sort of error with material-ui. The following code works:

```
class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      itemFormText: '',
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(info);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    /*
    fetch('http://192.168.86.31:5000/api/todoitems')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({
          items: result
        });
    });
    */
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Test
        <Items items={[]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Items extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const items = this.props.items;

    if (items.length === 0) {
      return <div>Nothing to do!</div>;
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <List>
        {
          items.map(i => (
            <ListItem
              key={i.id}
              primaryText={i.name}
              leftIcon={ i.isComplete ? <CheckBoxComplete /> : <CheckBoxIncomplete /> }
              />
          ))
        }
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ToDoList;
```

But as soon as I try to use any other component in place of "Test", I get the aforementioned "error" (quoted because the error is that "errors is not defined")... Still trying to step through in a debugger in the console but its really painful :\

UPDATE #4:
Turns out that material-ui's site links to a *very* old version of the API:
https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field

When you `npm install material-ui`, you get this old version. If you `npm install @material-ui/core` however, you get version 4.8.x. Apparently, the error handling code in this framework is pretty awful since the only error here was that I was passing in some arguments that the framework didn't recognize with the new version (`hintText` instead of `placeholder`). This caused the whole application to fail.

This doesn't solve why this error is bubbling up and eventually choking on a reference error to `errors`, but at least it gets my application working.

Comment: Show ToDoList code

Comment: Like I said in the post, I don't care so much about what the error is in the ToDoList as I do that the error handling is itself erroring out.

Comment: Edited to add ToDoList code